# echo user agent Casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

So I've set a new user agent using:

```
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36');
```

But I would like to obtain the newly modified user agent for testing purposes, so how does one print out a user agent that has been modified using `casper.js`?

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.echo(msg);
});
casper.evaluate(function() {
  console.log(window.navigator.userAgent);
});
```

Comment: and can I put it inside the returning value of a functions @hexid ?